# JavaFX modules not found when compiling (module.FindException)

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, compiler-errors

As far too many other people I also have the same problem that the JavaFX modules can't be found by the compiler. First of all I am using Eclipse and added my JavaFX location as a `User Library` in Eclipse ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGsWc.png)), added my projects dependencies ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKKwJ.png)) and made sure my `%PATH_TO_FX%` is set ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nikhj.png)).

After that I added the following arguments to `VM Arguments` in `Run Configurations`:

```
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-13\lib"
--add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web
```

Which results in the following message:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found

I do have a `module-info.java` file looking like this:

```
module MyProject {
    opens gui.controller to javafx.fxml;
    opens gui to javafx.graphics;

    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires java.sql;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires javafx.web;
    requires java.desktop;

    requires commons.logging;
    requires itextpdf;
    requires mysql.connector.java;
    requires org.json;
}
```

The complete commandline generated by Eclipse is shown below.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\javaw.exe
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-13\lib"
--add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web
-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
-p "D:\Bibliothek\Projekte\Git\MyProject\bin;D:\Bibliothek\Projekte\Git\MyProject\external\commons-logging-1.2.jar;D:\Bibliothek\Projekte\Git\MyProject\external\fontbox-2.0.17.jar;D:\Bibliothek\Projekte\Git\MyProject\external\itextpdf-5.5.13.1.jar;D:\Bibliothek\Projekte\Git\MyProject\external\mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar;D:\Bibliothek\Projekte\Git\MyProject\external\pdfbox-2.0.17.jar;D:\Bibliothek\Projekte\Git\MyProject\external\json-20190722.jar"
-m BuechereiSoftware/gui.BuechereiSoftware
```

Comment: Your --module-path must point to the lib folder inside the sdk and you must get rid of the " behind javafx.web.

Comment: I would suggest Use a other way to include dependencies into your project. Maven or Gradle, not only for development but also deployment. Also, try to Understand the "modular"-Aspect of java. There is the "module-info.java" file, in wich you should declare wich "modules" opens to your Project. 
You can do it with adding it to you classpath manually, but I would not recomment it since there are better ways now. 
Also be sure thet the Main of your Project does not Extend "Application". Your main should Launch the application.

Comment: @mipa I just changed the path to `...\lib` but it doesn't make any difference. I think the " was caused by my fault because I escaped the " in my module path like `...\javafx-sdk-13\"` so Eclipse tried to fix that. I corrected it now but it still doesn't work. Edited my question accordingly.

Comment: It looks like you did not follow the instructions here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ I think you havent used the User Library which you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by not using my custom JavaFX user library as a system library in Eclipse.

You can find this setting under `Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Build Path > User Libraries` then edit your JavaFX library and untick `System library (added to the boot class path)`. This should now look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL3Nd.png)